# Local site redirecting to live site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm trying to set up my web files locally for testing. I have my site files in my documents folder. I have xampp installed and have set up apache to use baseball.dev to bring up my local website. But when I try to use it, baseball.dev redirects to the live site. I'm not sure why.

My httpd-vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Kirst/Documents/GitHub/baseball-for-busy-   people/"
ServerName baseball.dev
ServerAlias www.baseball.dev
<Directory "C:/Users/Kirst/Documents/GitHub/baseball-for-busy-people/">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1             www.baseball.dev
```

There is an htaccess file in the folder with the website files. I thought this might be causing the problem, but when I moved it or commented it out, it had no effect. Here is that file:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#  Options +FollowSymLinks
  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Rewrite baseballforbusypeople.com as   www.baseballforbusypeople.com
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.baseballforbusypeople.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.baseballforbusypeople.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

 # Remove .html-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html 

 # End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines below are causing the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.baseballforbusypeople.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.baseballforbusypeople.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

As such, requests to `www.baseball.dev` will redirect to `www.baseballforbusypeople.com`.

On your dev server, comment the above lines and leave them uncommented on your production server.

Also, be sure to clear your browser cache if you are still experiencing the redirect.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious first choice would be to flushdns using `ipconfig /flushdns` on windows. Have you confirmed that the hostname www.baseball.dev does indeed point to 127.0.0.1

Also I have noticed that the htaccess file contains the following directive: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.baseballforbusypeople.com$ [NC]` as far as my knowledge stretches that would rewrite any request for the site that the .htaccess is contained in to the www.baseballforbusypeople.com site which I'm guessing is the live site.

Comment: I did ipconfig/flushdns (using instructions here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781949%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Then I checked the URL. It still redirects.

Comment: For the htaccess, I commented out the entire file, but it made no difference. The local URL still redirects to the live URL. I could delete the file entirely, but I'd like to keep it in there if I could so I have a backup to the one that is on the live site.

Comment: That's because the redirect was set to 301, Permanent. As such, you may need to clear your cache.

Comment: Thanks Mike, more informative answer, the cache clear and un-comment of the redirect should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. After commenting out the two lines and clearing the cache, it worked!

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious things are the hardest to see!

Comment: Of course! I forgot to flush the DNS. Though I did restart :( Thank you, this solved my issue.