# location.href redirects to live website rather than localhost

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

New to php and trying to sort this simple thing.

When I click on this `quote-button`, it redirects me to the live page rather than the localhost.

```
$('#quote-button').click(function(){
    location.href="quote-page.php";
    return false;               
});
```

So this does : `www.website.com/quote-page.php` rather than `localhost/quote-page.php`

I have newly installed XAMPP and using Apache and MySQL.

I have used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30425515/3770885 to sort out my localhost redirecting to live site. Its just this button click event causing the problem.

Comment: Why not use an anchor tag to redirect instead of using jQuery? As a user I hate it when someone redirects using JS, because you can't properly open a page to a new tab (using ctrl+click/middle mouse button) or use any of the other functionalities that the anchor tag gives you...

Comment: Just to be clear, you are on a page where it says `http://localhost/...` and when you click the button that fires this jQuery, it redirects you to your live site?

Comment: @Ivar Its a select drop down with two options, each to go to different page based on the option selected. I have just simplified the code here to highlight the issue. And yes to the second comment. I am at `http://localhost/...` and it redirects me to the live site on choosing a option from a select and clicking the button

Comment: Can you check your network tab and see how the page is redirected? Does it go immediately to your live site, or does it go to `localhost/quote-page.php` first and then redirect to the live site?

Comment: That's an interesting question - Yes it does go to localhost and then to live site. Why does that happen though?

Comment: Then the problem is not the jQuery, but probably something with .htaccess. I'm not that much of an expert on that, but it appears that the link you showed redirects every request from your localhost to the live site, so that could be it. It's only weird that it doesn't happen on the page where you show this button.